# JSON format validation without loading file

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3

How to validate JSON format without loading the file? I am copying files from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket. After JSONL files are
copied , I want to check if file format is correct in the sense curly braces and commas are fine.

I don't want to use json.load() because file size and number are big and it will slow down the process plus file is already copied so no need to parse it , just validation is requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streaming the file seems to be the way to go about it, put into a generator and yield line by line to check if the JSON is valid. The requests library supports streaming of a file.

> The solution would look something like this:

```
import requests
def get_data():
    r = requests.get('s3_file_url', stream=True)

    yield from r.iter_lines():


def parse_data():
    # initialize generator
    gd_gen = get_data()

    while True:
        try:
            ge_gen.__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            break

        # put your validation code here
```

Let me know you need a better clarification

Answer (score 1):

There is **no capability** within Amazon S3 itself to validate the content of objects.

You could **configure S3 to trigger an AWS Lambda function** whenever a file is created in the S3 bucket. The Lambda function could then parse the file and perform some action (eg send a notification or move the object to another location) if the validation fails.